# Aztec UA culture bonus count into increasing city border?

Tags: civilization-5

I was wondering does the Aztec ability helps the city border grow faster?

Comment: No it's not. Did you read the question?

Comment: The answer wasn't in the "duplicate" question, nor is it really implied by the title.  I've added it to the answer there now too, but I don't really think they should be duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the culture is added to your civilization's total, but it is not credited to any city and therefore does not help grow your borders.